# rank() equivalent for SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am using SQL Server 2000 so sadly common table expressions are out but I have the following 2 table structure:

Invoices

```
  id
```

InvoiceQueryReasons

```
  id
  invoice_id
  reason
  date_queried
```

I want to inner join from `Invoices` to `InvoiceQueryReasons` and only get 1 row for each invoice that selects the most recent `InvoiceQueryReasons` record.

If I was using a CTE with postgress I would do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         "i"."id", "iq"."reason", "iq"."date_queried", 
         rank() OVER (PARTITION BY "invoice_id" ORDER BY "date_queried" DESC) AS "invoice_query_rnk", 
    FROM "invoices" i 
    INNER JOIN "InvoiceQueryReasons" iq ON ("i"."id" = "iq"."invoice_id") 
    ) AS "iqrs" 
INNER JOIN 
    "invoices" ON ("iqrs"."id" = "invoices"."id") 
WHERE 
    ("invoice_query_rnk" = 1)
```

Apologies if the query is not exactly right, I am writing this on a non-dev machine.

How could I write a similar query in SQL Server 2000 where I do not have common table expression?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I always used to do this in SQL Server 2000:

```
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.PrimaryKey=(
 SELECT TOP 1 t2.PrimaryKey
 FROM Table2 t2
 WHERE t2.ForeignKey=Table1.PrimaryKey
 ORDER BY t2 DateColumn DESC
)
```

Comment: Agreed.  Its 2016 for crying out loud.

Comment: the decision to upgrade is not mine :) and I am pushing for it.  I'm just s poor humble contractor